# Can't get MacOS to work on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I have always tried to get any version of MacOS to run on virtual box but it just doesn't work. I have followed any tutorial of how to install it step by step but none have worked. I don't know if it's something that I am doing wrong or if it could be something else. There are two things that usually happen when I attempt to get it to work. This:

[image: Screenshot of where it gets stuck]

It usually gets to about there and then stops and does nothing more, or it pops up with a guru Meditation Error:

[image: Guru Meditation Error]

Any help or knowledge would be well appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to have much success running a vanilla OS X virtualized *client*[1] since Apple has never been friendly to running the OS X desktop in a VM.  You'll notice in this [VM roundup](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2411029,00.asp) that they reference 'You can't run a guest OS X system on a Linux or Windows machine, because OS X is licensed to run only on Mac hardware, and virtualization apps won't launch an OS X guest under Windows.'  So Apple doesn't make it easy and almost none of the major VMs will do it 'out of the box.'

That's not to say it can't be done.  To do this you're essentially going to be dealing with the same issues that people have when setting up a [Hackintosh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackintosh) which is probably what you want to research if you really want to go down this path.

[1] Running a VM host (i.e. running *other* operating systems in a VM under OS X) on the other hand works just fine